# Set background color of individual views in expandable listview

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview, android-view

I wish to set the background color of an individual view  in an expandable listview. Each time a group view is created in the expandable listview this method is called..

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, final boolean isExpanded,View view, ViewGroup parent)
```

I then check each view for a condition using the following..

```
if(booleanArray[groupPosition]){

} else {                        
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F0F0F0"));
}
```

IF the condition is TRUE, I leave the view's background as it is.
IF the condition is FALSE, I change the view's background color to #F0F0F0

What I'm seeing is that even when the TRUE condition is met, the view's background color is still getting set to #F0F0F0

Any ideas?

Comment: so at first run all the group rows are that color? no matter what the boolean array says?

Comment: @mango The booleanArray is initialized to contain all true elements on first run, so the background remains the default background color for the group.

Comment: this means that you need to have a condition for the true part of the conditional statement, perhaps set a command for the default color of the group view. your `convertView` must be working because once you've altered the color that same view is being sent to another position, it's not always the case than a new one will be inflated from scratch.

Comment: @mango Any setDefaultBackgroundColor command that I could do this with? I've tried setting to White using "#FFFFFF" but this disables the view's ability to turn blue when there is a touch/press on it

Comment: what color is it normally? have you tried setting the color to transparent? `view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);`

Comment: view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); does the trick... I don't think I can accept a comment as a solution but if I could I would

Comment: well the answer below satisfies the question above. I think it deserves the check as much as my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set color to default when your if is true. Because your views are reused you cant't "leave them as it is".